# fit() works as expected but then during evaluate() model performs at chance

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have noticed an issue where during evaluation(), I do not see the results I expect based on the results in fit(). I found numerous discussions online in which people have similar issues. For example, [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977) open issue discusses dropout layers and batch normalization as being possible causes, but also some people notice there may be an issue separate from dropout and batch normalization. For a beginner, its difficult to even know what exactly the issue is.

The network architecture I am using does contain batch normalization, but I am not sure if that is the issue.

The data for this demo can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wQZbCuw8cI9cyZIKz956wNLfgfz-o3c3/view?usp=sharing).

This script clearly demonstrates the issue I am having:

```
import random
import os
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
HEIGHT_WIDTH = 299
BATCH_SIZE = 10
VERBOSE = 2

SANITY_SWITCH = False

print('starting script')

net = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,  # 'imagenet',
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=2,  # 1000,
    classifier_activation='softmax'
)

print_output = True
def utility_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    global print_output
    if print_output:
        print(f'y_true:{y_true.numpy()}')
        print(f'y_pred:{y_pred.numpy()}')
        print_output = False
    return 0


net.compile(
    optimizer='ADAM',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy', utility_metric]
)

net.run_eagerly = True

class_map = {'dog': 0, 'cat': 1}

def preprocess(file):
    imdata = mpimg.imread(file)
    imdata = cv2.resize(imdata, dsize=(HEIGHT_WIDTH, HEIGHT_WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    imdata.shape = (HEIGHT_WIDTH, HEIGHT_WIDTH, 3)
    imdata /= 127.5
    imdata -= 1.
    return imdata, class_map[os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))]

train_data = [f'data/Training/cat/{x}' for x in os.listdir('data/Training/cat')] + [f'data/Training/dog/{x}' for x in os.listdir('data/Training/dog')]
test_data = [f'data/Testing/cat/{x}' for x in os.listdir('data/Testing/cat')] + [f'data/Testing/dog/{x}' for x in os.listdir('data/Testing/dog')]

random.shuffle(train_data)
random.shuffle(test_data)

if SANITY_SWITCH:
    tmp_data = train_data
    train_data = test_data
    test_data = tmp_data


def get_gen(data):
    def gen():
        pairs = []
        i = 0
        for im_file in data:
            i += 1
            if i <= BATCH_SIZE:
                pairs += [preprocess(im_file)]
            if i == BATCH_SIZE:
                yield (
                    [pair[0] for pair in pairs],
                    [pair[1] for pair in pairs]
                )
                pairs.clear()
                i = 0
    return gen

def get_ds(data):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        get_gen(data),
        (tf.float32, tf.int64),
        output_shapes=(
            tf.TensorShape((BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT_WIDTH, HEIGHT_WIDTH, 3)),
            tf.TensorShape(([BATCH_SIZE]))
        )
    )
print('starting training')
net.fit(
    get_ds(train_data),
    epochs=5,
    verbose=VERBOSE,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    workers=16,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=False
)
print('starting testing')
print_output = True
net.evaluate(
    get_ds(test_data),
    verbose=VERBOSE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    workers=16,
)
print('script complete')
```

The full output is here:

```
starting script
2020-12-22 15:29:33.896474: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-12-22 15:29:34.184215: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.186083: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.188086: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.190088: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.192124: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 4 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:84:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.194144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 5 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:85:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.196095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 6 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.197451: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 7 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:89:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:34.208178: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-22 15:29:34.301110: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:34.348641: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:34.370185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:34.459524: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:34.471473: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:34.599447: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-12-22 15:29:34.634806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
2020-12-22 15:29:34.635371: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2020-12-22 15:29:34.680254: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2000105000 Hz
2020-12-22 15:29:34.687348: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x561e331d4820 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-22 15:29:34.687415: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-12-22 15:29:35.617673: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.619368: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.621161: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.622953: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.624745: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 4 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:84:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.626508: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 5 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:85:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.628264: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 6 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629460: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 7 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:89:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629581: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629633: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629685: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629733: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629788: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629837: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-12-22 15:29:35.629886: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.657298: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.659638: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678371: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678500: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N Y Y Y N N N N 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 1:   Y N Y Y N N N N 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678569: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 2:   Y Y N Y N N N N 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678597: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 3:   Y Y Y N N N N N 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678624: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 4:   N N N N N Y Y Y 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678652: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 5:   N N N N Y N Y Y 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678678: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 6:   N N N N Y Y N Y 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.678705: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 7:   N N N N Y Y Y N 
2020-12-22 15:29:35.703703: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10689 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.711407: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 8534 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.716593: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 10689 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.721879: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 10689 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.726952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:4 with 10689 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 4, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.732126: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:5 with 10689 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 5, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.736838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6 with 10689 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 6, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.740357: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:7 with 108 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 7, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:89:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746472: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x561e387dea00 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746517: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746537: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (1): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746577: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (2): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746594: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (3): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746614: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (4): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746645: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (5): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746664: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (6): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2020-12-22 15:29:35.746694: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (7): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
starting training
Epoch 1/5
2020-12-22 15:29:48.307104: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-12-22 15:29:51.694232: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:81] Running ptxas --version returned 256
2020-12-22 15:29:51.796020: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: ptxas exited with non-zero error code 256, output: 
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
2020-12-22 15:29:52.577156: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
y_true:[[1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
y_pred:[[0.58956003 0.41043994]
 [0.63762885 0.36237112]
 [0.53731585 0.46268415]
 [0.5393683  0.4606317 ]
 [0.90735996 0.09264001]
 [0.552977   0.44702297]
 [0.7115651  0.28843486]
 [0.4068687  0.59313136]
 [0.5482196  0.4517804 ]
 [0.4330527  0.56694734]]
72/72 - 81s - loss: 0.9134 - accuracy: 0.5417 - utility_metric: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
72/72 - 81s - loss: 0.7027 - accuracy: 0.5847 - utility_metric: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
72/72 - 83s - loss: 0.6851 - accuracy: 0.5819 - utility_metric: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
72/72 - 83s - loss: 0.6810 - accuracy: 0.5944 - utility_metric: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
72/72 - 83s - loss: 0.6895 - accuracy: 0.5625 - utility_metric: 0.0000e+00
starting testing
y_true:[[1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]]
y_pred:[[0.39538118 0.6046188 ]
 [0.39505056 0.6049495 ]
 [0.39406297 0.605937  ]
 [0.3947329  0.60526717]
 [0.3935887  0.60641134]
 [0.39452523 0.60547477]
 [0.39451653 0.6054835 ]
 [0.39475334 0.60524666]
 [0.39559898 0.604401  ]
 [0.3951175  0.60488254]]
90/90 - 37s - loss: 0.7157 - accuracy: 0.5000 - utility_metric: 0.0000e+00
script complete
```

The part of the output to focus on is accuracy:

Training Epoch 1:  0.5417

Training Epoch 2:  0.5847

Training Epoch 3:  0.5819

Training Epoch 4:  0.5944

Training Epoch 5:  0.5625

Evaluation: 0.5000

I've also included the raw output of the network in two cases.
One during training:

```
y_true:[[1.]
     [1.]
     [0.]
     [1.]
     [1.]
     [1.]
     [1.]
     [0.]
     [1.]
     [1.]]
y_pred:[[0.58956003 0.41043994]
     [0.63762885 0.36237112]
     [0.53731585 0.46268415]
     [0.5393683  0.4606317 ]
     [0.90735996 0.09264001]
     [0.552977   0.44702297]
     [0.7115651  0.28843486]
     [0.4068687  0.59313136]
     [0.5482196  0.4517804 ]
     [0.4330527  0.56694734]]
```

And one during testing:

```
y_true:[[1.]
     [1.]
     [0.]
     [0.]
     [0.]
     [1.]
     [1.]
     [0.]
     [0.]
     [1.]]
    y_pred:[[0.39538118 0.6046188 ]
     [0.39505056 0.6049495 ]
     [0.39406297 0.605937  ]
     [0.3947329  0.60526717]
     [0.3935887  0.60641134]
     [0.39452523 0.60547477]
     [0.39451653 0.6054835 ]
     [0.39475334 0.60524666]
     [0.39559898 0.604401  ]
     [0.3951175  0.60488254]]
```

I find it confusing why during the testing, the variation of output from image to image seems to be tiny. This seems to be related to the source of the problem, but I do not know what causes it.

I have run this script many times now, and some things are consistent. The accuracy during evaluation is always exactly at chance. There is always low variation in y_pred during evaluation, and all of the output seems to be the same label (so for example, during evaluation the model may report every single input image as being "dog").

Sometimes during training, the accuracy goes above 60%. This does not affect the issue. I could go onward to increase the size of the dataset and number of epochs and try to improve training results, but I'm afraid of moving forward without first understanding why evaluation results are so strange as they are now.

Comment: How many examples do you have for the two classes in both training and test datasets?

Comment: Why do you initialize your weights as None?

Comment: @Feri, in the example I showed the test set had 450 per class (900 total) and the train set was 360 per class (720 total)

Comment: @Sebastian R. in the research study I'm developing this for, we think it's more appropriate to try without transfer learning first

Comment: @MattGroth I guess you should initialize your weights as random variables then.

Comment: @Sebatian R. As you can see here: https://keras.io/api/applications/inceptionresnetv2/ the weights are initialized as random variables.

Comment: @MattGroth I suspect these datasets are too different, so the pattern from the first is useless for the second. Try to mix the both datasets. I would also train with test_data and test with train_data. Another suggestion - run `model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data)` to see dynamics

Comment: @Andrey, I've tried mixing the datasets and the results are the same. The validation test still always predicts every image as the same class.

I've also tried adding the validation_data argument you suggested. This showed me that the problem always occurs, even after the first epoch. In every single epoch, the validation test seems to predict every image to be the same class.

Comment: As of now, I'm still stumped. If anybody would like to try to solve this by debugging it themself, everything is there for you. The code works with mainstream libraries and the dataset is uploaded and can be downloaded from a link in the question. I tried to make it easy for others to set up on their own system.

Comment: It has nothing to do with data itself for sure. I have just done a simple experiment I always do in such cases. I took just 10 examples from training set and use it as both training/validation dataset. If overfits easily after 6-7 epochs. The joke is... validation data always return the same result. So I have 0.02 loss on training and 0.7 on validation (with the same data). Quite a conundrum.

Comment: I also changed the way data is fed into the model. Instead of dataset from generator I just provided arrays. Plus I changed preprocessing step according to documentation.

Comment: If you remove `BatchNormalization` layers everything is all right, so I guess they are to be blamed

Comment: @Proko that's extremely helpful, thank you. The question then is how to prevent this issue from occurring without removing the batch normalization layers since they are an important part of the model. A full answer would probably require some conceptual understanding of how batch normalization layers are misbehaving. I've read through some of the discussion linked in my question but still haven't figured it out myself how the issue described in other discussions is manifesting itself in this script.

Comment: I submitted an issue on Tensorflow's github since this is very weird to me: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46414 hope that's ok

Comment: @Proko, thanks for continuing to look into this. I looked at the code in the issue you posted on github and ran it myself using your data, and the CustomInceptionResNetV2 worked as it did for you, while the regular InceptionResNetV2 (with bn layers) did not. So I'm glad we identified an issue with batch normalization layers and that the tf team is looking into this.

Comment: On the other hand, I think there is more going on here. Perhaps this is a completely seperate issue, but when I took your script with CustomInceptionResNetV2 and kept everything exactly the same but replaced the data with my own, it still didn't work. Still getting an evaluation loss that's identical each epoch and exactly 0.5 validation accuracy each time. Importantly, this is with the code you posted which doesn't have batch normalization layers. So there must be a completely seperate issue on top of the batch normalization issue you identified, and wondering if you might have any clues.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a very similar problem with the [MobileNetV3Large model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNetV3Large).

It issue was when setting `weights=None`, it resets all the parameters, including the BatchNormalization metrics used during evaluation.

More than that, as a friend pointed out to me, the default BatchNormalization's momentum is set to 0.999, which means, the BatchNormalization parameters used during evaluation only (during training it uses the batch means/variances) move very, very slowly.

That's ok if you train for millions of steps, over several epochs. For a small dataset, these parameters were not significantly changed and the evaluation was all broken.

If your problem is like mine, a quick fix was to set the momentum of all BatchNormalization layers to 0.9. This can be achieved with this simple recursive function:

```
def SetBatchNormalizationMomentum(model, new_value, prefix='', verbose=False):
  for ii, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
      SetBatchNormalizationMomentum(layer, new_value, f'{prefix}Layer {ii}/', verbose)
      continue
    elif isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
      if verbose:
        print(f'{prefix}Layer {ii}: name={layer.name} momentum={layer.momentum} --> set momentum={new_value}')
      layer.momentum = new_value
```

I hope this helps you as well -- it worked here.

(edited) .: Code setting the BatchNorm momentum in MobileNet [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/mobilenet_v3.py#L509).