# why is tensorflow/keras and training and validation metrics way off from each other?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

a description of my project, I am trying to train a network that recognizes a picture containing a number from 0 to 9 and categorizing it as such.
my model is as follows

```
model = Sequential(
[
    tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128),  LeakyReLU(alpha=.3),
    Dense(128),  LeakyReLU(alpha=.3),
    Dense(128),  LeakyReLU(alpha=.3),
    Dense(128),  LeakyReLU(alpha=.3),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
]
```

)

```
model.compile(
optimizer='adam',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['categorical_accuracy','accuracy','mae']
```

)

I dont't think it is a matter of overfitting.The data is coming from a data generator that is creating new pictures with digits using opencv's putText function using random fonts, font sizes/thickness as well as random rotates and shifts meaning all the data is completely unique. I have also verified the data visually and there doesn't seem to be anything  unusual with it.
I have done two experiments.
first I created two separate generators, a training and validation generator,
at the end of the epoch, the the previous validation data becomes the training data and new data is created for the validation, and yet when this happened I didn't see the training metrics drop at all.
Next I trained the model with a static set of training data and it uses that exact same data for validation.

train_x,train_y=new_data(3200)

train_x=train_x/255

history = model.fit(train_x,train_y,steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=15, verbose=1,validation_data=(train_x,train_y))

and yet in that instance despite being the exact same data  the validation metrics is drastically worse than the training metrics as shown in the attached images.
Does anyone know what's going on?
Am I just misunderstanding something about the training process in keras?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH84n.png)

Comment: Could you provide more than the 3 firsts epochs? Also could you try using a smaller model. I do think with 40% val accuracy you won't suffer a lot by reducing to 1 LeakyReLu(128)

Comment: This literally fits the definition of overfitting. And overfitting is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the batch normalization layers in the MobileNetV2 model, specifically with batch normalization momentum parameter
as discussed in :

[fit() works as expected but then during evaluate() model performs at chance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415799/fit-works-as-expected-but-then-during-evaluate-model-performs-at-chance)

a quick fix is to change that the default momentum of .999 to .9