# Overfitted model performs poorly on training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What can be the cause of accuracy being >90% while model predicts one class in 100% cases in multiclass clasification problem? I would expect that the overfitted model with high accuracy for training data will predict well on training data.

Model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1./255., offset=0.0),
  mobilenet_custom,
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
```

Where `mobilenet_custom` is a `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` model with random weights and input is modified to have 7 channels.

I am trying to classify frames of a clip into three classes. The training data set is kind of balanced:

```
Total count:  15849
Labels[ A ]:  3906
Labels[ B ]:  5955
Labels[ O ]:  5988
Batch Shape X:  (32, 224, 224, 7)
Batch Shape y:  (32, 3)
```

The accuracy is >90% after 2 epochs. (the val_accuracy is around 35%)

However I also record confusion matrices at each epoch end using the `Callback` class using the following function to collect data for the confusion matrix:

```
def _collect_validation_data(self, arg_datagen):
    predicts = []
    truths = []
    print("\nCollecting data for epoch evaluation...")
    batch_num_per_epoch = arg_datagen.__len__()
    for batch_i in range(batch_num_per_epoch):
        X_batch, y_batch = arg_datagen[batch_i]
        y_pred = self.model.predict(X_batch, verbose=0)
        y_true = y_batch
        predicts += [item for item in np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)]
        truths += [item for item in np.argmax(y_true, axis=1)]
        print("Batch: {}/{}".format(batch_i+1, batch_num_per_epoch), end='\r')
    print("\nDone!\n")
    return truths, predicts
```

Every time the confusion matrices look like following:

[image: Confusion matrix for Training data]

When I saved the values of `y_pred` and `y_true` that are passed to compute the accuracy it confirms that the accuracy is calculated correctly.

[image: Data from which the metrics are computed - last batch of 2nd epoch]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the batch normalization. When tried on model without batch normalization layers like vgg16, the results were as expected on training data - values of the confusion matrix build from prediction on training data were mostly on the diagonal (when the training accuracy was high).

More detailed discussion here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977

A possible solution here: [fit() works as expected but then during evaluate() model performs at chance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415799/fit-works-as-expected-but-then-during-evaluate-model-performs-at-chance?noredirect=1#comment116131855_65415799)